# x-header missing for Outlook MeetingItems when received

Tags: vsto, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I am using the following approach in a VSTO Outlook Addin (using Addin-Express library) to set a custom x-header attribute on mails  and other items you can send from Microsoft Outlook, like meetings. It's a security classification which is evaluated by a mail gateway appliance for making sure encryption is activated on outgoing mails, depending on the classification. Inside the organization, it will just be displayed on the receiving side, which is Outlook 2016 desktop client.

Before sending, I set the x-header property like this:

```
 string headerNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string /{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/";     
 public void SetHeader(PropertyAccessor acc, string header, string value)
    {
        acc.SetProperty(headerNamespace + "x-mycustomheader", value);
    }
```

I always receive the header for mails, but not for Meetings. I know there is an associated appointment, but I tried reading the header from any object I could think of

On the receiving end, I get the current item from the explorer or inspector window and try to retrieve that header. The attribute is not visible in OutlookSpy and it's not inside the transport header. Is it possible that Outlook stored it somewhere else, or has it been removed? This process is working fine for MailItem types.

I stripped some parts like releasing the com objects for better readability. OutlookMeetingItem2 is a wrapper class. I have two alternative methods for reading the header, one is the PropertyAccessor and the other is used here, both can't find the header attribute.

```
        using (OutlookMessageItemWrapper outlookItem = OutlookMessageItemFactory.GetMessageItem(currentItem))
       {
         object outlookitemMapi = outlookItem.MAPIOBJECT;
                classificationString = mapi.GetHeader(outlookItem.MAPIOBJECT, Constants.CLASSIFICATIONHEADER);

                if (classificationString == "" && outlookItem is OutlookMeetingItem2)
                {
                    OutlookMeetingItem2 meetingItem = outlookItem as OutlookMeetingItem2;
                    MeetingItem meeting = meetingItem.Item;

                    object mapiObject = meeting.MAPIOBJECT;
                    classificationString = mapi.GetHeader(meeting.MAPIOBJECT, Constants.CLASSIFICATIONHEADER);
                    if (classificationString == "")
                    {
                        AppointmentItem appointment = meeting.GetAssociatedAppointment(false);
                        if (appointment != null)
                        {                           
                            classificationString = mapi.GetHeader(appointment.MAPIOBJECT, Constants.CLASSIFICATIONHEADER);
                        }
                    }                   
                  }
                }
```

Comment: It might be that a server removed those xHeader. Can you please give us more infos if this email is only transfered via one server of it here are others involved?

Comment: When exactly are you setting the header? Application.Item.Send event? When do you check the incoming header? On the MeetingItem in the Inbox? Or the AppointmentItem in the Calendar folder?

Comment: I am setting the header on the "new" mail, usually located in the draft folder until the send button is clicked. This is done with a custom form in the reading pane.

Comment: It could be something on the server, there is a difference if I send the meeting outside the organisation or inside. The header is lost between internal mailboxes.